# SQL Server , insert trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

```
recid  | EffectiveFrom | EffectiveTo
------------------------------------
   1   | 2012-11-25    | 2012-11-30
   2   | 2012-11-26    | null
```

I need a trigger that checks if the new date falls between `effectivefrom` and `effectiveTo`
and stops the insert..

Comment: if you have 100 rows - **which** `effectiveFrom` and `effectiveTo` should we check against?? All of them? And also: which **column** of the newly inserted row isn't allowed to fall in between those two dates? You need to provide more information!

Comment: What have you tried? Or are you expecting someone to write the code that you can copy and use?

Comment: See: [An Introduction to Triggers - Part 1](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i) or just **search** on Google or Bing! There are **thousands** of introductory articles... http://bit.ly/U5Qq7U

Comment: @marc_s, It needs to check all the rows

Comment: And **which** column isn't allowed to be between `effectiveFrom` and `effectiveTo` ?

Comment: EffectiveFrom is not allowed to be between the two dates

Answer (score 0):

Try this  :

```
USE {yourDB}; 

CREATE TRIGGER insertRecord ON {tblName}
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @EffectiveFrom DATE;
    DECLARE @EffectiveTo DATE;
    DECLARE @newDate DATE;
    SET @newDate = GETDATE();  -- DATE WHICH YOU WANT TO CHEK
    SELECT @EffectiveFrom = EffectiveFrom FROM INSERTED;
    SELECT @EffectiveTo = EffectiveTo FROM INSERTED;

    IF (@newDate > @EffectiveFrom AND @newDate < @EffectiveTo)
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [{yourDB}].[dbo].[{tblName}] 
        SELECT * FROM INSERTED;
        PRINT 'DATA SUCCESSFULLY ADDED.'
        END
    ELSE PRINT 'ERROR : DATE IS NOT IN BETWEEN EffectiveFrom and EffectiveTo DATE'
END


INSERT INTO [{yourDB}].[dbo].[{tblName}] VALUES(CAST('24-NOV-2012' AS DATE),CAST('30-NOV-2012' AS DATE))
```

MESSAGES --result
ERROR : DATE IS NOT IN BETWEEN EffectiveFrom and EffectiveTo DATE

```
INSERT INTO [{yourDB}].[dbo].[{tblName}] VALUES(CAST('24-NOV-2012' AS DATE),CAST('02-DEC-2012' AS DATE))
```

MESSAGES -- result
(1 row(s) affected)
DATA SUCCESSFULLY ADDED.

Comment: This is **NOT** going to work if the `INSERT` statement happens to insert **more than one row**; what will your `SELECT @EffectiveFrom = EffectiveFrom FROM INSERTED;` really select?? Which of the 10 inserted rows is being checked?? Triggers in SQL Server are called **once per batch** (of potentially more than one row!) and `Inserted` can contain 1, 5, 10, 100 rows. The trigger is **NOT** fired once per row

Comment: Yes, its true..it will run for inserting single row at a time.